# serializers validation method is not validating list of objects for the first time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.4, serialization

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ("name", "email", "phone")
        extra_kwargs = {
            "email":{"required":True},
        }


    def validate_email(self, email):
        qs = Customer.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This email is already existed")
        return email

    def validate_phone(self, phone):
        qs = Customer.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
        if qs.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This Phone  is already existed")
        return phone
```

views.py

```
class CustomerApi(SerializerMixin, APIView):

    ......
    .........

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(
                        serializer.errors,
                        status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                    )
```

json

```
[
{
    "phone": "123",
    "name": "name1",
    "email": "123@ll.cc"
},
{
    "phone": "123",
    "name": "nam32",
    "email": "123@ll.cc"
}

]
```

the above customer json list have two objects with same email and phone . But it is not validating the email and phone(validation methods are not working) when i create if for the first time. But once it get created, the second time when i try to create the customer with the same list, validation method is working as expected. 
i couldn't trace out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Your code here

    def validate(self, validated_data):
        emails = [x['email'] for x in validated_data]
        if len(emails) > len(set(emails):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplication email in data")
        phones = [x['phone'] for x in validated_data]
        if len(phones) > len(set(phones):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplication phone in data")
        return validated_data
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. validated data gives only one dict at a time.

Comment: its good answer but validated data gives only one dict at a time. is there any other way to do it. i tried it with create method as well. but the problem is at a time it gives only one dict.